# How to get the excel sheet name in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I have an interface to upload excel sheet in Nodejs. After uploading it how can i get the name of excel sheet? i need to display this excel sheet name in a text box. How it is possible?

I would like to get  file name and if mutiple sheets are there then each sheet name also.

Comment: Are you talking about the file name or the actual sheet in the file?

Comment: I would like to get file name and if mutiple sheets are there then each sheet name also.

Comment: Ok, and where are you stuck? What have you tried? Have you researched on google?

Comment: I answered this question in another place, See here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56533049/how-to-get-excel-sheet-names-in-javascript/69098525#69098525](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56533049/how-to-get-excel-sheet-names-in-javascript/69098525#69098525)

Answer (score 0):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// `bodyParser` includes `multipart`
app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/', function(req, res, next){
// assuming <input type="file" name="upload">

var path = req.files.upload.path;
var name = req.files.upload.name;

// copy...
});
```