# How to get excel sheet names in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the list of the sheets from an excel file in order to display it in a combobox. The idea is that the user can select the file that he want to import from an excel file instead of typing and avoid typo errors

```
function getSheets(file)
{
    var reader;
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e)
    {
        var data;
        var workbook;
        var sheets;
        data = e.target.result();
        workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'binary'});
        sheet = workbook.SheetNames;
        for (var i in sheets.items)
        {
            console.log(sheets.items[i].name);
        }
    }
    reader.onerror = function(ex)
    {
        console.log(ex);
    }
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}
```

The following error is displayed when the function is executed:
`Function expected` on line: `data = e.target.result();`
Any idea of how should I face it?

Comment: Is it supposed to be `e.target.result` instead of `e.target.result()`?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I pass that point, however now I am getting the following error: XLSX is not defined. Are these supposed to be the libraries that I should use: https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/blob/master/jszip.js[link](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/blob/master/jszip.js)
https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/blob/master/xlsx.js[link](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/blob/master/xlsx.js) or there are others?

Comment: Yes , you need a library . Parsing Excel is not built into javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Detail explaination can be found [Here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/reading-a-excel-file-using-html5-jquery/)

```
                 sheet.forEach(function (y) { /*Iterate through all sheets*/  
                     /*Convert the cell value to Json*/  
                                     var  exceljson = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[y]);  
                       
                     
                 });
```

Answer (score 0):

In NodeJS you can use the [Node XLSX (NodeJS excel file parser & builder)](https://github.com/mgcrea/node-xlsx).
There is a parse method that reads the Excel file and gives you an array of all it's sheets.
Then you could loop the array and get the name of each sheet and all the data.
To Install the package use:

```
npm install node-xlsx --save
```

This code will print all the sheet names in an Excel file:

```
var xlsx = require('node-xlsx');
const worksheetsArray = xlsx.parse('example.xlsx'); // parses a file
worksheetsArray.forEach(sheet => {
    console.log(sheet.name);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the following lib: npm install xlsx

```
const xlsx = require('xlsx')
const workbook = xlsx.readFile(file); //Here you should pass the file path
const sheetList = workbook.SheetNames; //Array of sheet names.
console.log(sheetList)
```